# Insert Array of JSON-s into Postgres table

Tags: postgresql

I have an array containing JSON of the following form:

```
[
  {
    "country": "ANY",
    "category": "poetry"
  },
  {
    "country": "ES",
    "category": "science"
  }
]
```

What I currently do is - iterate over the JSON-s in the Array in Python and insert them into the DB table one by one like so:

```
sql = 'insert into table_name (country, category) values (%s, %s)'
vars = (country, category)
app_utils.run_query_pool_commit(con_pool, sql, vars)
```

I'm curious if there's a more elegant way of doing such kind of bulk inserts without having to make a loop and inserting the objects one by one.

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of Postgres are you using? Newer versions have extensive JSON support and you may be able to get the server to do it for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there are many json functions built into [postgresql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html)

the function you are looking for json_to_recordset()  the command will look something like this

```
insert into table_name (country, category) 
   select * from json_to_recordset( '[
  {
     "country": "ANY",
     "category": "poetry"
   },
   {
      "country": "ES",
      "category": "science"
    }
   ]') as x(country text, category text);
```

On how elegant this is does not matter,  something has to parse the json text and turn it into a record,  postgresql may be able to do it faster than python.
Neither side looks pretty and neither side is fast because of the casting and text parsing that is going on